# android c2dm - Is it possible to use my own authentication service at client side?

Tags: android, architecture, android-c2dm

I am reading [introduction of android c2dm implementation guidelines](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#intro). I am happy to use google authentication for server. But i want to use my own authentication server for client side. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly possible, but if you want C2DM's to reach your user's phone, the phone needs a Google account associated with it.